# How to create list of lists

Tags: python, list

Here is what I have:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 7, 11, 8, 55, 89, 1, 3, 8]
```

How can I get this broken down by 5 to the list of lists.

The desired outcome is:
`[[1, 2, 7, 11, 8], [2, 7, 11, 8, 55], [7, 11, 8, 55, 89],[11, 8, 55, 89, 1], [8, 55, 89, 1, 3], [55, 89, 1, 3, 8]]`

Here is what I've tried:

```
indices = [0,1,2]
for i in indices:
   new.append(mylist [i])
   indices = [x+1 for x in indices]
   print(indices)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should look at slice notation, i.e. mylist[i:i+5] should give you a slice of the list from indice `i` with length 5. You can then append this slice to an output list

Comment: `out = [ll[i: i+5] for i in range(0, len(ll), 1)] ` ?

Comment: There is no way that you tried 3 indices when you need 5 numbers. Please try and debug your programs yourself before asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 7, 11, 8, 55, 89, 1, 3, 8]

>>> [mylist[i:i+5] for i in range(6)]
[[1, 2, 7, 11, 8], [2, 7, 11, 8, 55], [7, 11, 8, 55, 89], [11, 8, 55, 89, 1], [8, 55, 89, 1, 3], [55, 89, 1, 3, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following two options are available.

1. List Generative

```
mylist = [1, 2, 7, 11, 8, 55, 89, 1, 3, 8]
res = [mylist[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(mylist)-4)]
```

2. a loop, since it is constructed sequentially and can simply exit the loop once the length is not satisfied (see also the previous approach for a limit on the length of the loop)

```
mylist = [1, 2, 7, 11, 8, 55, 89, 1, 3, 8]
new = []
for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
    if len(mylist[i:i+5]) == 5:
        new.append(mylist[i:i+5])
    else:
        break
```